# Cannot select checkbox using Capybara

Tags: checkbox, capybara

I can't get my test to set a checkbox. Tried all kinds of hints found on Google, but nothing seems to work.

The source for the checkbox is

```
<div class="ish-field buttons-conditions">
<div class="accept-conditions">
<input tabindex="30"
type="checkbox"
class="ish-input-regular-news"
id="RegisterUserFullEmail_Accepted-1"
value="true"
name="RegisterUserFullEmail_Accepted"
```

The checkbox is visible on the page.
I would expect to be able to simply do: `check("RegisterUserFullEmail_Accepted-1")` but that doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What driver are you using with Capybara?  What error exactly are you getting? What makes you say "the checkbox is visible on the page"?  Have you tried  find(:css, "#RegisterUserFullEmail_Accepted-1") to see if the input is actually on the page, or find(:css, "#RegisterUserFullEmail_Accepted-1", visible: :hidden ) to see if its on the page but non-visible?

Comment: Thanks for answering!

Comment: Thanks for answering! I stated "visible on the page" because I see the checkbox on the rendered page. But maybe that was too simplistic. Only the `find(:css, "#RegisterUserFullEmail_Accepted-1", visible: :hidden )` yields a result, so that means that the checkbox is really not visible. Right? What I tried next was: `find(:css, "#RegisterUserFullEmail_Accepted-1", visible: :hidden).set(true)`. But this gives the error: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError).

Comment: Correct, as the element is not currently visible to capybara on the page.  Is it on a dialog that you need to click something else to have appear/slide out or something?  or are you using some JS library that is replacing/restyling the checkbox with some kind of widget? If it's a publicly accessible site, post the url and I'll take a look at the page

Comment: The URL is https://www.plus.nl/registreren. The checkbox I want to set is the one all at the bottom: "Ik accepteer de accountvoorwaarden". In order to get to that point you have to fill the obvious fields at the top (name, address, etc.) and then select 'your' supermarket. After doing that, you can check the box and register yourself.

Comment: Are you using selenium as your driver?  If you are try reverting to selenium-webdriver 2.47.1 -  I know I read about some changes/issues in 2.48 that were causing problems, not sure what the outcome was though.

Comment: ok -- after looking at the page - the checkbox is actually hidden with display: none and then an image is inserted using a css ::before pseudo element (probably to make the checkboxes look the same across all browsers) -  because of this you'll need to click on the label instead of the checkbox   `find(:css, 'label', text: 'Ik accepteer de accountvoorwaarden').click`   or   `find(:css, 'label[for="RegisterUserFullEmail_Accepted-1"]).click` or something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the page you're attempting to drive https://www.plus.nl/registreren the checkboxes are actually hidden with css display: none, and then a css ::before pseudo element is used to insert an image of a checked or unchecked box (probably to make checkboxes look consistent across all browsers).  Because of this you can't just check the checkbox, instead you can click on the label for the checkbox.  In this case either of the following should do that

```
find(:css, 'label', text: 'Ik accepteer de accountvoorwaarden').click
find(:css, 'label[for="RegisterUserFullEmail_Accepted-1"]').click
```

since in this case the label has a link inside it which appears to be at the middle of the link (where it would get clicked) we can look at what else is in the label and there is a separate span element in it which we can click on without clicking on the link so

```
find(:css, 'label', text: 'Ik accepteer de accountvoorwaarden').find(:css, 'span').click
find(:css, 'label[for="RegisterUserFullEmail_Accepted-1"] span').click
```

Comment: Thank for your support Tom! However, both don't work yet. Both click on the link with the 'account voorwaarden' (terms & conditions), not on the checkbox. Any ideas for that?

Comment: Hmmm -- they will click in the middle of the label - which may end up being on the linked word unfortunately -  looking at the html there is a separate span element with an * in it inside the label so one could click on that -- adding examples to my answer